# Understanding why an OPA27 is unsuitable for a window comparator and a MC1458DR is better

Tags: operational-amplifier

I'm a junior electronics engineer and have a question about a window comparator circuit I've built:
[image]

**Circuit Explanation:**

The op amps have a tight reference voltage on their non-inverting terminals. U1A pin 3 is set to 5.025V with precision resistors and U1B pin 5 is set to 5V.

The inverting pins of both op-amps are tied to a 0-10V input signal that varies depending on an external system.

The outputs of both op amps are tied to the LED of an opto isolator (U1A output = Anode of the opto-isolator, U1B output = Cathode of the opto-isolator). When the input of the external system providing the 0-10V signal is in the window of 5V - 5.025V, the opto-isolator will be active as U1A pin 1 will be high and U1B pin 7 will be low therefore pulling the opto-isolator to ground.

**The Problem:**

I originally tried using 2 x OPA27 op amps instead of a dual package MC1458. When I initially tested the circuit, the opto-isolator would not switch and the voltage on the inverting terminals of the OPA27 devices started to "follow" the 0-10V signal (by this I mean as the voltage on the inverting terminals swung linearly between 0-10V, the non-inverting terminals no longer remained at their fixed precision voltages as defined by the resistor ladder).

My question is why did the OPA27 not work in a window comparator configuration while the MC1458 has no problem? The MC1458 is not a comparator. It is, much like the OPA27, a general purpose op-amp. They both have similar Common Mode Rejection but I can't seem to understand why the MC1458 is better for the job (and ultimately, why the MC1458 worked but the OPA27 did not).

Any help would be greatly appreciated - Apologies in advance if anything similar has been asked or if this is a really rookie question.

Comment: Please draw the exact circuit that wasn't working as expected.

Comment: Please add the resistor values, the output of the circuit the provides the input signal for the comparator, the opto-isolator model and the slope of the signal.

Comment: OPA27 datasheet link would be useful : are there input protection devices like diodes between the inputs, to prevent large differential input signals?

Comment: @BrianDrummond - Yes, input diodes is the answer. Figure 6. https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa27.pdf

Comment: CT123, I think you have your answer in the comments. Brian identified the general issue of concern (that diode-protected inputs prevent the input difference from exceeding 700 mV) and Mattman has pointed up that the OPA27 presents exactly that concern. You haven't responded yet. Do you understand why diode protection is a problem when using the OPA27 as a comparator?

Comment: And why not use a comparator when building a comparator circuit?  I can't understand why people insist on trying to use op-amps as comparators.  Op amps can have several issues when used as comparators.

Comment: Thank you all for your help. Apologies for the slight delay in getting back to you all. It is very clear that if I would have spent 10 minutes understanding the internal circuitry of the op amp that I would have noticed the input protection diodes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Understanding the datasheet specs incl. Absolute Maximum and schematic is essential, takes time and well worth the effort.

[image]

The lack of input resistance reduces noise and the clamping of inputs protects them from damage as Vbe = -5V reverse max. But it is possible to protect the inputs other ways allowing +/- 30V differential input.

Comment: Tony - Greatly appreciate your answer. Thank you for taking the time to give me a reasoned response. As mentioned above, if I actually took the time to read the datasheet a bit more in detail, I wouldn't have had to ask this question! You mention that "... It is possible to protect the inputs other ways allowing +/- 30V differential input" - I assume you mean with other op amps and not the OPA27 due to the fixed internal clamping diodes?

Comment: roger that.....